# Display all the checked items as comma separated using jquery

Tags: jquery

In the below code i have a variable thatparticularsel which gives the value of only that particular checkbox which is checked and the alltheselectedvalues will return all the checked checkboxes values suppose if i have checked 2 previously and current 1 it will give me 3 and i need to display those 3 as comma separated but currently i am able to bind only one

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), e.g: `myArray.join(', ')`

Comment: it is binding id to dropdow instead it should bind innerText: "checked1↵select" as comma separated

Comment: You should add values (of checked checkboxes) into an array and then use `join` to make them comma separated.

Comment: can you show me how to do that and bind the innertext as comma seperated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can add the values to an array and use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to display them, for example:

**HTML**

```html
<input type='checkbox' value='1' />
<div>Value 1</div>
<input type='checkbox' value='2' />
<div>Value 2</div>
<input type='checkbox' value='3' />
<div>Value 3</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**JS**

```js
$('input').on('change', function () {
    // filter checked checkboxes and add the inner text of its next element to an array
    var values = $('input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).next().text();
    }).get();

    // values.join(', ') is what you are looking for
    $('div#result').text(values.join(', '));
});
```

Output example:

`Value 1, Value 2`

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The following demo has multiple checkboxes and a special one that checks/unchecks the other checkboxes programmatically. All details are commented in demo.

```js
/*
This will check all checkboxes is #ALL is checked and vice
versa
*/
$('#ALL').change(function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
});

/*
If any checkbox is changed by the user...
Define a empty array
Get each checkbox..
if a checkbox is checked...
...get its value and push that value into that array
Once each checkbox is done display the array in output
*/
$(":checkbox").on('change', function(e) {
  let checked = [];
  $(':checkbox').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        checked.push($(this).val());
      }
    }
  });
  $('output').val(checked);
});
```

```html
<input id='ALL' type='checkbox' value=''> ALL<br>
<hr>
<input type='checkbox' value='1'> 1<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='2'> 2<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='3'> 3<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='4'> 4<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='5'> 5<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='6'> 6<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='7'> 7<br>
<output></output>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it should not happen in this way

Comment: @abc Ok, explain how it should happen. Without HTML I'm guessing what you mean by value and where this list of values are to displayed if at all.

Comment: @abc you said, *"suppose if i have checked 2 previously and current 1 it will give me 3 and i need to display those 3 as comma separated "* So run my demo, check two checkboxes and look at the bottom...do you see a comma separated list of two checked values? Now check one more checkbox now look at the bottom...do you see a comma separated list of three checked values?